# my sync function doesn't wait for all the subfunctions to finish

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, promise

i'm trying to make an api that can see if i made a post on imgur and i'm really close to finish but my function returns before the end

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

```
ddb.scan(params1, function(err, data) {
    if (err) callback(null, err);
    else {
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            for (var o = 0; item.links && item.links.L && o < item.links.L.length; o++) {
                var taction = "";
                var treaction = "";
                var action = item.links.L[o].S.substring(0, item.links.L[o].S.indexOf(' '));
                var saction = action.substring(0, action.indexOf(':'));
                var reaction = item.links.L[o].S.substring(item.links.L[o].S.indexOf('=')+2);
                var sreaction = reaction.substring(0, reaction.indexOf(':'));
                for (var z = 0; item.accsplus && item.accsplus.L && z < item.accsplus.L.length; z++) {
                    if (item.accsplus.L[z].S.substring(0, item.accsplus.L[z].S.indexOf(':')) == saction) 
                        taction = item.accsplus.L[z].S.substring(item.accsplus.L[z].S.indexOf('token:')+6);
                    if (item.accsplus.L[z].S.substring(0, item.accsplus.L[z].S.indexOf(':')) == sreaction)
                        treaction = item.accsplus.L[z].S.substring(item.accsplus.L[z].S.indexOf('token:')+6);
                }
                if (taction == "" || treaction == "") log += "no token for this service @" +action+reaction + " ";
                else{
                    console.log("testing " +action+reaction)
                    if ((saction == "imgur" || saction == "reddit") && (sreaction == "imgur" || sreaction == "reddit")) {
                        if (saction == "imgur")
                            imgur(action.substring(action.indexOf(':')+1), item, taction, reaction.substring(reaction.indexOf(':')+1));
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        callback(null, "ok");
    }
});

async function imgur(action, whom, token, reaction) {
    if (action =="") return;
    var requestdone = false;
    var toret;
    var old = "";
    var needed = action;
    if (action == "onpost" || action == "onrem") needed = "postnbr";
    if (action == "onlike" || action == "ondis") needed = "likenbr";
    console.log("imgur " + needed);
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    async function request(success) {
        const response = await fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/account/me/images", requestOptions)
        const json = await response.json();
        return await success(json);;
    }
    function success(json) {
        var worked;
        if (needed == "postnbr") actual = (json.data.length);   
        if (needed == "likenbr"){
            if (json.data[0].vote == null || json.data[0].vote == "null") actual =  (0);
            actual = (json.data[0].vote);   
        }
        if (needed == "postnbr") console.log("postnbr = " + actual);
        if (needed == "likenbr") console.log("likenbr = " + actual);
        if (whom.old && whom.old.L && whom.old.L.length > 0){
            for (var p = 0; old == "" && p < whom.old.L.length; p++){
                if (whom.old.L[p].S.substring(0,whom.old.L[p].S.indexOf(':')) == "imgur"+needed)
                {
                    old = whom.old.L[p].S.substring(whom.old.L[p].S.indexOf(':')+1);
                    if (action == "onpost" && old < actual) worked = true;
                    if (action == "onrem" && old > actual) worked = true;
                    if (action == "onlike" && old < actual) worked = true;
                    if (action == "ondis" && old > actual) worked = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (worked)
        {
            return imgur(reaction, whom, token, "");
        }
        upold("imgur", needed, whom, actual)
    }
    await request(success)
}

var getactual = function(service, token, needed) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if (service == "imgur"){

        }
        if (service == "reddit"){
            console.log("do reddit mofo");
        }
    })
};

function upold(service, needed, whom, actual) {
    var toret = [];
    if (whom.old && whom.old.L.length > 0){
        for (var m = 0; m < whom.old.L.length ; m++) {
            if (whom.old.L[m].S.substring(0,whom.old.L[m].S.indexOf(':')) != service+needed)toret.push(whom.old.L[m].S);
        }
    }
    toret.push(service+needed + ":" +actual);
    param = {
        TableName:"biipboop",
        Key:{
            "email": whom.email.S
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set old=:r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":r":toret
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };
    docClient.update(param, function() {});
}
```

};

so far it seems like the function works and the request subfunction is called but the main doesn't wait for an answer and returns Promise {} then the log does happen once the success completes itself but i don't have my variable at the end of the imgur function, it just logs itself when finished

EDITED :
since you asked for the actual code i had, i copy pasted it brutally
i have my scan working well, gets all my user and then it doesn't wait for function "imgur" to give a proper answer and just leaves triggers it and iterate through the foreach.

i'm trying to use lambda and ddb through aws

the logs do arrive in this order : 

`testing imgur:onpostimgur:onlike
imgur postnbr
testing reddit:postreddit:onpost
postnbr = 3`

Comment: Which exact code isn't waiting for what to finish?  You say "main doesn't wait for an answer", but there's no `main` function in your code so I don't know what that statement means or what code it isn't waiting for.  Also, is `updateold()` asynchronous?  What does it do?  There are way, way too many unknowns in this question.  Please read about creating a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add enough information to your question.

Comment: Also, no point in this: `.then(function(msg) {return msg;})` and `return await success(json);;` can just be `return success(json);`.

Comment: So, what is your `main()` not waiting for?

Comment: If `main()` calls `imgur()` which does `return request(success)` and `request()` does `return await success(json)`, but `success()` has no return value so that means that `request()` will resolve to a promise with an `undefined` value.  So, the promise that `request()` returns does not communicate back any value.  It returns a promise that resolves to `undefined`.

Comment: @jfriend00 as you asked i added my main to the post
and all your path is good but the success does return ("you made a post recently") if a post has been made, if not, it returns null and null is printed indeed

Comment: Well `imgur()` returns a promise.  So, `console.log(imgur("onpost", accounts[i], accounts[i].token))` will always log an unresolved promise, every time.  Even if that promise is eventually going to get a resolved value, it won't have it yet since promises are never resolved synchronously.

Comment: What is `updateold`? Does it have asynchronous code too?

Comment: Where do you declare `actual`?

Comment: What do you expect the `console.log` in `main` to output (in different scenarios)?

Comment: This question is unclear. Please make sure to explain *exactly* what the problem is, how to reproduce it, what the expected output is...

Comment: thanks to all for your help, i'm new in here i don't really know if i should post all my code or a nice edit, anyway i edited and now it's my actual code

Comment: The question is still unclear.  You don't clearly state what the problem is.  I asked you an hour ago what `main()` is not waiting for and you haven't answered that.   We STILL don't know what the actual problem is.  What do you observe as the output?  What do you want the output to be that is different than what you observe. Clear questions here are critical. With a good, clear question, you will usually get a quick and accurate answer here fairly quickly.  I've also posted an answer that explains your  your `console.log(imgur(...))` will never show anything interesting - no response on that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are returning data from `imgur` looks really off to me.. This would be a lot easier, in my opinion, if you turned `imgur` into an `async` function so that you can `await` for the data that `request` returns.

```js
async function imgur(action, whom, token) {
    var toret;
    var old = "";
    var needed = "postnbr";

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    async function request(success) {
        const response = await fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/account/me/images", requestOptions)
        const json = await response.json();
        return /* await */ success(json); // <-- shouldn't have to await this
    }
    function success(json) {
        old = "2";
        if (needed == "postnbr") actual = (json.data.length);   
        if (needed == "postnbr") console.log("postnbr = " + actual);
        if (action == "onpost" && old < actual)                     
            return("you made a post recently");
        updateold("imgur", needed, whom, actual)
    }
    return await request(success); // .then(function(msg) {return msg;});
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```js
async function useImgur() {
  const imgurData = await imgur('some-action', 'some-whom', 'some-token');
  console.log(imgurData);
}

useImgur();
```

...or like:

```
imgur('some-action', 'some-whom', 'some-token')
  .then(imgurData => console.log(imgurData))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `imgur()` returns a promise.  So,

```
console.log(imgur("onpost", accounts[i], accounts[i].token))
```

will always log an unresolved promise, every time.  Even if that promise is eventually going to get a resolved value from

```
return("you made a post recently");
```

it won't have it yet since promises are never resolved synchronously.  The soonest the promise that `imgur()` returns will be resolved is on the next tick of the event loop which is after your `console.log()`.

---

You can change the code to this to log the value:

```
async function main(accounts) {
   for (var i = accounts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     let val = await imgur("onpost", accounts[i], accounts[i].token);
     console.log(val);
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that some code paths through `imgur()` do not return a value which is probably not a desired design, thus sometimes the resolved value from the `imgur()` promise can be `undefined` and sometimes not.